Is the Extensionality Axiom circular?
In Elements of Set theory by Enderton (1977, p17), the Extensionality Axiom is stated as:

If two sets have exactly the same members, then they are equal:
$\forall A\forall B[\forall x(x\in A\iff x \in B) \Longrightarrow $ A=B]

Suppose A = {x, y} and B = {z, w}. To check whether A = B holds, according to the axiom, one of the conditions we need to check is $x\in B$. However, isn't the process of checking $x\in B$ already implicitly using the notion of equality between two sets, the notion that the axiom is trying to define (which is circular)?
For example, if we find that x (which is a set, since every object is a set in set theory) is "equal" to at least one of the two elements (or two sets) in B, we can say that $x \in B$; if x is not "equal" to none of the two elements in B, $ x \notin B$.
I know that I am being too picky, for we can (literally) see whether $x \in B$ holds with our eyes without using the notion of equality. So I believe the initial question is reduced to the following question:

Does the way we use the vocabulary $\in$ rely on our ability to visually compare two symbols (in the above example, we compare x and z).
Can't this vocabulary be used by blind people?


No it's no circular. This axiom says every set is only defined by its "elements", and no extra property, which forces the membership relation to mimick the "real" membership relation. If the model (of some set theory other than ZFC) has urelements, then without extensionality, urelements are equal to the empty set, which they clearly aren't.

Extensionality is not a definition of equality.

Equality is a primitive from first-order logic, not something defined in set theory.  It is prior to set theory. Extensionality is an axiom stating conditions for sets to be equal.

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668244/what-is-the-right-interpretation-of-the-axiom-of-extensionality

The extensionality axiom is not trying to do anything, and in particular it is not trying to define equality.
The extensionality axiom is not a definition of equality, as said by @spaceisdarkgreen in the comments.
Instead, one should think of the set relation $\in$ as already defined, and one should think of the set relation $=$ as already defined, and one should think of the extensionality axiom as a statement that these already-defined relations $\in$ and $=$ are required to satisfy.
In general, it is a misconception to think that axioms "define" things. Perhaps instead you should think that axioms characterize things, in that they state properties that a mathematical structure must satisfy in order to be a structure of a certain type. The group axioms state properties that a mathematical structure must satisfy in order to be a group. The axioms of set theory state properties that a mathematical structure must satisfy in order to be a set theoretic universe.

Just to add to this great answer: we can imagine other structures besides sets where this axiom wouldn't hold. For example, if we were axiomatising graphs, and using $\in$ to mean "is a vertex of", then it wouldn't hold, because two graphs can have the same set of vertices without being the same graph.

"In general, it is a misconception to think that axioms "define" things." I disagree. If something satisfies all the axioms of [thing], then it is [thing]. So the axioms define what [thing] is. If I write down all the axioms that integers satisfy, then anything that satisfies those axioms is isomorphic to the $\mathbb N$. "What $\mathbb N$ is" has no meaning beyond the axioms it satisfies.

@Acccumulation: There is a subtle linguistic distinction going on here. In the context of this post, the OP was essentially asserting that the extensionality axiom "defined" equality, which is just wrong-headed. That is the context in which my answer was written. I have also seen this wrong-headedness in group theory posts where the poster asserts that the axioms of a group define the group operation. You're right in one way, though: in mathematical practice there is an ambiguity between, say, the definition of a group and the axioms of a group.

@Acccumulation Axioms are things that if true, you can proof other things true about the structure.  The counting numbers as a concept exist independent of which set of axioms you use to characterize them; this can be demonstrated by the fact we could count before we wrote down the axioms.

@Accumulation: "If I write down all the axioms that integers satisfy, then anything that satisfies those axioms is isomorphic to the $\mathbb N$."  Not true if first order logic is the framework for axioms.  Instead we speak of those constructs that satisfy a specified collection of axioms as models of a theory.  Generally a theory can have models that are not isomorphic to one another.
